# Нужна программа или .bat для поиска строки из файла и вывода её в отдельный файл

Tags: xml, поиск, строки, замена

Есть программа, которая генерирует содержимое в формате .XML вот такого содержания:

[image]

Из этого XML файла нужно bat/exe файлом найти нужные строки и вывести их в отдельный файл meta.txt (с перезаписью содержимого файла).

В данном случае должно вывести в файл meta.txt это:

```
ZHU - Faded (Original Mix)
```

(Получается, нужно найти всё от начала строки, до первого попавшегося, затем взять всё ДО строки, потом так же с, полученные `Faded (Original Mix) ZHU` поменять местами, между ними поставить знак '-' и записать в файлик.)

В целом должно получиться так:
программа выдала XML. Я открыл bat/exe файл и в нужном месте создался txt с одной строкой формата "Исполнитель - Название".

Второй элемент не должен обрабатываться (Basto & Yves V - Cloud Breaker (Basto Radio Mix), он отсекается как левый ненужный код.

Проблема в том, что XML код отформатирован ещё и в одну строку. Для удобства выложил сам файл: https://yadi.sk/d/wbAfWxlndw62T
И его исходник в одну строку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?><ELEM_LIST><ELEM PLAYER_NAME="Плеер" SCH_ID="0" SCH_NAME="Default" STATUS="playing"><START_TIME>09:47:17</START_TIME><START_DATE>2015-01-08</START_DATE><BLK_TYPE>Б</BLK_TYPE><TYPE></TYPE><NAME>Faded (Original Mix)</NAME><ARTIST>ZHU</ARTIST><AUTHOR></AUTHOR><ALBUM></ALBUM><DBID></DBID><FILE_NAME>D:\music\311014\ZHU - Faded (Original Mix)1.mp3</FILE_NAME><DURATION>00:03:52</DURATION></ELEM><ELEM PLAYER_NAME="Плеер" SCH_ID="0" SCH_NAME="Default" STATUS="preloaded"><BLK_TYPE>Б</BLK_TYPE><TYPE></TYPE><NAME>Cloud Breaker (Basto Radio Mix) (DFM ID)</NAME><ARTIST>Basto &amp; Yves V</ARTIST><AUTHOR></AUTHOR><ALBUM></ALBUM><DBID></DBID><FILE_NAME>D:\music\12082012\Basto &amp; Yves V - Cloud Breaker (Basto Radio Mix) (DFM ID) .mp3</FILE_NAME><DURATION>00:03:18</DURATION></ELEM></ELEM_LIST>
```

(То, что выше на картинке, это я отредактировал его немного, чтобы удобнее читалось.)

Comment: @alex-platinum, а почему вы хотите решить эту задачу именно bat'ником? Есть же более приспособленные для этого инструменты.

Comment: То ли я не понял проблему, то ли не нашел. Чем xsl не устраивает?

Comment: да впринципе хоть чем, главное чтобы в итоге был формат в .exe
Программа генерирует XML приблизительно раз в 5 минут (как только начинает играть mp3 в плейлисте)
И эта программа должна запускать после этого программу в exe, которая уже вытаскивает строку в формате "Исполнитель - название" и сохраняет в файл, затем уже другая программа подхватывает этот текстовый файл и отправляет метаданные на сервер icecast. Вот как то так.

Comment: Ну так msxsl.exe, скорее всего, легко найти почти на любом компьютере.

Comment: @maxleo, я, например, у себя его не нашёл. Однако, ничто не мешает его загрузить и прописать в PATH. @alex-platinum, на вашем месте я бы прислушался к совету @maxleo. А ещё я бы посоветовал присмотреться к Cygwin, MSYS или PowerShell. Возможности стандартного командного процессора Windows весьма ограничены, использовать unix-like shell гораздо удобнее.

Comment: Про msxsl.exe щас погуглю, спасибо)

Каким образом можно вытащить эти значения? (причём только 1 название и исполнителя которые в самом начале)

Comment: @alex-platinum, гуглите XSLT, это язык, предназначенный для описания преобразований xml-документов.

Comment: Попробовал с помощью утилиты msxsl.exe преобразовать, выводит пустое значение почему то(

Comment: @fori1ton, не совсем так: язык xsl, а xslt - формат файла для него (t stands for template). 

@alex-platinum, вы бы xslt опубликовали, штатные телепаты в отпуске.

Comment: Всё, проблему решил экранированием кавычек. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам скорей всего подойдет стандартная команда Windows 
- Findstr.exe
Данная команда умеет искать строки по регулярным выражениям.
Синтаксис примерно такой:

```
findstr /O ^<ARTIST^>.*?^<\/ARTIST^> <My.xml >OUTPUT.txt
findstr /O ^<NAME^>.*?^<\/NAME^> <My.xml >>OUTPUT.txt
```

Символ ^ - это экранизация символов в BAT
А конструкция `\/` - это экранизация в regexp